# Как написать знак \ в print python

Tags: python, python-3.x, текст, sublime-text

```
gg = list(r"C:\Program Files\Python310")
print(gg[0].count(r"\"))
```

через r пишет ошибку.

попробовал реплейсом вставить \ не работает.

Как написать \ знак.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Знак `\` написать очень легко, нужно его просто экранировать ещё одним таким же знаком: `\\`. У вас в коде просто сразу две проблемы:

- Вы превращаете строку в список символов, `gg[0]` - это один символ `C`, в нём нет никаких `\`
- К сожалению, `r` не работает нормально со знаком `\` в конце строки перед закрывающей кавычкой.

Итого, рабочий код:

```
gg = [r"C:\Program Files\Python310"]
print(gg[0].count("\\"))
```

Вывод:

```
2
```